# Windows Service Start and Stop C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I have developed a windows service to get fingerprint attendance data from a fingerprint machine time to time by using a thread and insert into ms SQL database. When I run the service in my local computer it's working fine but when I install and run it in server 2012 the service start and then stop.Please help me out.

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        new LogManagement().WriteToLog("Service Started -" + DateTime.Now);
        new LogManagement().WriteToLog("Thread Started" + DateTime.Now);
        RunThread();
    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        new LogManagement().WriteToLog("Service Stopped -" + DateTime.Now);
    }
    public void RunThread()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DeviceChecker));
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Name = "DeviceCheckingThread";
        thread.Start();
    }
    private void DeviceChecker()
    {
        //Process reading data and insert into database
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
```

Comment: If all else fails, try using Topshelf and see if installing it through that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer).

I think you need to call `SetServiceStatus` method (from advapi32.dll) inside your `OnStart` method, or Service Control Manager will shut your service down, if it takes to long for startup.